# Using the compare tool during an object import in Dynamics AX 2009

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, ax

I'm trying to import a list of objects into a Dynamics AX 2009 system.  The problem that I have is that the object IDs differ for all the objects that I'm importing.  I'm doing the import manually, and so as part of this I need to compare each object (and there's a few), because they all show as different.

My question is: is there a way to either tell Dynamics to not show the object ID as a difference, or else to fool it into thinking they're the same?

Comment: If you find an answer useful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your scenario, you could export the project from the source without using IDs. When importing the project to another system, there will not be ID conflicts (obviously).

But before you decide whether or not to export without ID, you should understand the pro's and con's of ignoring the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to ignore object ids.

However, you could make a code change in \Classes\SysTreeNode\comparableTextListProperties and delete the offending id property.

Answer (score 0):

.XPOs are text files, so you can use a text editor and do a find and replace of object ids outside of AX before trying to import it.